# How to center an image on a page with lp?

Tags: printing, printer, lp

OS is Debian 10. I'm trying to print a batch of images with lp. So far so good. Scaling works great, for example.

Right now I'm printing with:

```
lp -d "$printer_name" -o ppi=100 -o position=center 1.png
```

However, positioning is not functioning. Leaving position off centers the image top to bottom, but puts it on the left side of the page. `position=right` has the same result. `position=center` has the same result. `position=left` has the same result. `position=top` puts it at the top left. `position=bottom` puts it at the bottom left. It's like `lp` just can't move the image over to the right side of the page for some reason.

What is going on here?

Printing in gimp or firefox works correctly and I can definitely print on the rest of the page.

Comment: Try using `lpr -P "$printer_name" -o ppi=100 -o position=center 1.png` (note: `lpr` instead of `lp`)

Comment: Same result with lpr sadly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately I could not find a fix for this, but I was able to add enough of a transparent border to center the images on the page:

`mogrify -bordercolor transparent -border 200 *.png`